# How can I use a variable to define a file for InputStream / .getResourceAsStream(variableForTextFiles) in Java?

Tags: java, getresource

Right now I have a text file for this to read hard-coded as KlebsiellaMicro.txt. What I need is a variable, `fileName`, to dynamically pull in a different txtfile name based on the template selection in a different java file.

Under the file `Micro.java`:

```
static void getFullMicroArray() throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = Data.class.getResourceAsStream("KlebsiellaMicro.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    ...
```

variable `fileName` is under the following code in a different file named `MainWindow.java`:

```
JButton btnLoadMicroTemplate = new JButton("Load Template");
btnLoadMicroTemplate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String fileName = null;
    String templateSelection = comboTemplateSelect.getSelectedItem().toString();
    switch(templateSelection){
        //case must match dropdown selections exactly
        case "MRSA Culture Respiratory": fileName = "MRSARespiratory.txt";
        case "Klebsiella Non-Culture Blood": fileName = "KlebsiellaMicro.txt";
        default: fileName = "MRSARespiratory.txt";
                 break;
    }
    ...
```

How can I pass this `fileName` variable through to dynamically switch the file names in the `getResourceAsStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to change the getFullMicroArray() function in Micro.java to take in a String variable getFullMicroArray(String fName).  Then call getFullMicroArray(fileName) at the end of the case statement in MainWindow.java.

Then change `InputStream in = Data.class.getResourceAsStream("KlebsiellaMicro.txt");` to `InputStream in = Data.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);`